# jQuery length failed to validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML :

```
<div id="product_imgfiles_container" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail product_imgfiles">
            <img src="./user/product/2016/04/07/2608/0024454001460020491/img/29310931.jpg   ">
            <a href=""><span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> delete</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail product_imgfiles">
            <img src="./user/product/2016/04/07/2608/0024454001460020491/img/29340931.jpg   ">
            <a href=""><span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> delete</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail product_imgfiles">
            <img src="./user/product/2016/04/07/2608/0024454001460020491/img/29311931.jpg   ">
            <a href=""><span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> delete</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have this jquery :

```
$.getJSON("controller/ctrl.dropzonejs-imgfiles.php?dir=XXX",function(json){                         
    $.each( json, function( key, val ) {
        alert (val);

        if (!$("#product_imgfiles_container img[src="+val+"]").length){
            alert ("this val not in your HTML yet");
        }

    });
});
```

when there's no IF statement, `alert (val);` can show all json data. but when I need to validate with `.length`, it stops the iteration. and I still can't get `alert ("this val not in your HTML yet");` executed.

how to use `.length` properly to validate if the src path from json already exist in HTML or not?

Comment: What you have should work, assuming that the `val` coming from your JSON is correct. Could you please add a sample of the JSON retrieved in the AJAX request to the question.

Comment: `"` inside `"` wrapped string will break the string... Try `$("#product_imgfiles_container img[src='+val+']")`

Comment: *"it stops the iteration, and I still can't get `alert`"* That tells you an error is being thrown. Which means there will be useful information in the web console. You can also use the debugger built into your browser to single-step through the code to see what's going wrong. My guess is that `val` contains a string with a space or similar, but **you** don't have to guess, you can watch it run.

Comment: @RayonDabre: No, look again. The goal is to use the value of `val` there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I don't know which "he" you mean, but the OP isn't ensuring there are quotes around `val`'s value, and Rayon's code just puts `[src='+val+']` **literally** in the string. Putting quotes around it would look like this: `$("#product_imgfiles_container img[src='"+val+"']")`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : the val contains string like this `./user/product/2016/04/07/2608/0024454001460020491/img/29310931.jpg `

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, you're right, misread Rayons' comment

Comment: @RobertHanson that's not event close to the `src` property, as they have only the filename.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I just missed by a quote! I guess you need to specify how `jQ` attribute selector expects `value(in quotes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an error from jQuery/your browser's selector engine. You need to put the value you get from `val` in quotes:

```
$("#product_imgfiles_container img[src='"+val+"']")
// Note -------------------------------^-------^
```

You can use the web console to see errors.

Comment: you're right, bro! that's makes the error and break the iteration. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**change you code to be the following :-**

```
 if ($("#product_imgfiles_container img[src='"+val+"']").length==0){
            alert ("this val not in your HTML yet");
        }
```

Comment: Code dumps are rarely *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*. (This is also just a duplicate of an existing answer.)

Comment: Not Duplicated i tested it and worked on it by myself not getting it from anywhere

Comment: I never said you *copied* it (if you had I'd've downvoted and flagged for a mod), just that when you see that an answer you've written has ended up just being a duplicate of one that's already there, you should just delete it, as it's not useful to duplicate existing answers. That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the "val" value getting from JSON is not valid, the "val" is having complete path including image name.

So better use with image name only instead of complete path.

```
img src="/dummy/image/logo_header.png"

var x = $("img[src$='logo_header.png']");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change your if condition to

```
if (!$("#product_imgfiles_container img").prop('src') == val){
            alert ("this val not in your HTML yet");
        }
```

Comment: If you did it this way you would need to loop over every single `img` and check the property